# how to hide original image path using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide the original image path from my WordPress site. wherever it does not work. but other rules are work properly.

I had tried like

```
RewriteRule ^wp_unisol/img/([^/]+)$ wp_unisol/images/$1 [L]
```

but it is not working.

when I check on .htaccess checker it shows true.

I need image path like bellow

**Original Path:** 
https://clickthedemo.com/wp_unisol/images/noimgavailable.jpg

**Expacted Path:** 
https://clickthedemo.com/wp_unisol/img/noimgavailable.jpg

I know this question ask before but it does not help

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file located? Is it inside the root directory? or inside the `wp_unisol` directory?

Comment: it is located inside the `wp_unisol` directory

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wp_unisol/

    RewriteRule ^img/([^/]+)$ images/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Put this in the `.htaccess` file in the `wp_unisol` directory.

Comment: Where is the `wp_unisol` located on the web server? Is it in the root?


EDIT: Nevermind, i just noticed the URL. Well, the exact same structure works for me. Maybe mod_rewrite isn't enabled on your web server?

Comment: `wp_unisol` located in sub-directory and mod_rewrite is enabled on my webserver. if mod_rewrite is disabled on webserver than my other rules does not work

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^img/([^/]+)$ images/$1 [L]
```

And make sure to put it at the top of the `.htaccess` file or at least before the WordPress rewrite rules.